# Figuring out an array formula syntax

Tags: regex, google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Does anyone know what this does and explain it to me?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(MMULT(N(REGEXMATCH(
 TRANSPOSE('Form Responses 1'!C2:C),B2:B)),N(IFERROR(
 (EOMONTH('Form Responses 1'!B2:B,-1)+1=A2))*IFERROR(
 LEFT('Form Responses 1'!D2:AU,FIND(" ",'Form Responses 1'!D2:AU)-1)))),
 COUNTA(B2:B),COUNTA(G1:AU1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ARRAYFORMULA` - auto-calculate for each row/column in a given range
`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` - limits outputting range for example: "output only first 3 columns and first 10 rows"
`MMULT` - multiplies two ranges/matrixes (columns * rows)
`N` - converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`
`REGEXMATCH` - searches for an exact or partial value in the range and outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE`
`TRANSPOSE` - turns rows into columns or columns into rows
`IFERROR` - deals with errors like `#N/A`, `#NUM!`, `#VALUE`, `#REF!`, `#DIV!` if found
`EOMONTH` - for a given month it will output the last day date
`LEFT` - is able to extract a given number of characters from the left end from a given range
`FIND` - searches value in a given range
`COUNTA` - counts all non-empty cells in a given range